# StringDate to Date coming in different Time in SimpleDateFormat in java

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat, localdate

```
    /*I want the same Date of my String has
     Tried with couple of options but nothing worked 
     pasting some of code here */

    public void stringToDate() {

        //Current format "13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100000000 PM" in Melbourne Timezone
        //Required Format yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS in Melbourne Timezone

        String inputAM = "13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100000000 PM";
        try {
            DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S aa");
            Date d1 = df1.parse(inputAM);
            System.out.println("Date-1: " + d1); //Fri Feb 14 19:07:48 AEDT 2020

            DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S aa");
            Date d2 = df2.parse(inputAM);
            System.out.println("Date-2: " + d2); //Tue Jan 14 19:07:48 AEDT 2020

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat etDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        TimeZone etTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne");
        etDf.setTimeZone(etTimeZone);

        DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a");
        Date d3;
        try {
            d3 = df3.parse(inputAM);
            System.out.println("Date-3: " + d3); //Fri Feb 14 07:07:48 AEDT 2020
            System.out.println("Date-4: " + etDf.format(d3.getTime())); //2020-14-02 07:07:48.000
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date object SimpleDateFormat not parsing timestamp string correctly in Java (Android) environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636491/date-object-simpledateformat-not-parsing-timestamp-string-correctly-in-java-and) This? [Timestamp convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705924/timestamp-convert)

Answer (score 3):

First, for most purposes don’t convert a date and time from one string format to another. In your program keep date and time as proper date-time objects, not strings. When you accept string input, parse it first thing. Only when you need to give string output, format your date-time into a string in the required format.

Second, use java.time, the modern Java date and time API for all of your date and time work. It is so much nicer to work with than the old, poorly designed and long outdated classes including `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.

### Parse your input using java.time

```
    //Current format "13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100000000 PM" in Melbourne Timezone
    DateTimeFormatter currentFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("d-MMM-uu hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne");

    String inputAM = "13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100000000 PM";

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputAM, currentFormatter).atZone(zone);

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output so far is:

> 2020-02-13T15:21:08.100+11:00[Australia/Melbourne]

### Format using java.time

```
    //Required Format yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS in Melbourne Timezone
    DateTimeFormatter requiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String formatted = dateTime.format(requiredFormatter);
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

> 2020-02-13 15:21:08.100

### What went wrong in your code?

When I first tried your code, parsing failed for `FEB` because your code doesn’t specify locale, and my Java uses a non-English default locale.

Correcting that I was able to parse the string and got the same results as you (only in my time zone). What happens: `SimpleDateFormat` takes uppercase `S` to mean *milliseconds*, 1000ths of seconds, no matter how many `S` there are and no matter how many digits are in the string to be parsed. So 100 000 000 milliseconds were added to your date and time. That’s a little more than one day. So you got 14 Feb instead of 13 Feb, and also a wrong time of day. In contrast to the modern `DateTimeFormatter` upper case `S` means *fraction of second*, so it handles both `SSSSSSSSS` and `SSS` the way we expect.

Uppercase `DD` is for day of year, so using this for parsing you got the 13th day of the year (the same as 13 January) plus your 100 000 seconds.

Uppercase `HH` is for hour of day from 00 through 23. Parsing using `HH` gave you 03:21 of day (same as 03:21 AM) plus your 100 000 seconds no matter that it said `PM` in your string.

### Link

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

There are three **major** problems in your code:

1. You have used `.SSSSSSSSS` for the fraction of a second whereas the `SimpleDateFormat` does not support a precision beyond milliseconds (`.SSS`). It also means that you need to limit the digits in the fraction of a second to three.
2. You have used `HH` for a time in 12-Hour format (i.e. with am/pm) whereas the [correct pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this is `hh`. The symbol, `HH` is used for a time in 24-Hour format.
3. You have used `DD` for **Day in month** whereas the correct pattern for this would be `dd`. The symbol, `DD` is used for **Day in year**

Apart from this, I recommend you always use `Locale` with a date parsing/formatting API because parts of a date-time string are represented in different ways in different `Locale`s.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdfInput.parse("13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100 PM");

        // Print Date#toString
        System.out.println(date);

        // Print the date-time in a custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(date));

        // If required, format date with a timezone
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutputWithTz = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS[zzzz]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdfOutputWithTz.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));
        System.out.println(sdfOutputWithTz.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thu Feb 13 15:21:08 GMT 2020
2020-13-02 15:21:08.100
2020-14-02 02:21:08.100[Australian Eastern Daylight Time]
```

**Some facts about legacy API:**

1. The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.
2. The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>◊</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive() // For case-insensitive (e.g. AM/am) parsing
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uu hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);       
        
        // Parse the date-time string
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("13-FEB-20 03.21.08.100000000 PM", dtfInput);
        
        // Print LocalDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(ldt);
        
        // Print the date-time in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(ldt.format(dtfOutput));
        
        // If required, convert the LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-13T15:21:08.100
2020-13-02 15:21:08.100
2020-02-13T15:21:08.100+11:00[Australia/Melbourne]
```

**Note:**

1. If your date-time string has always 9 digits for the fraction of a second, you can replace `.SSSSSSSSS` with `.n`.
2. For [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the symbol, `u` means **year** whereas the symbol, `y` means **year-of-era**. It doesn't make any difference for a year in the [AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) era, but it matters for a year in the BC era. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) to learn more about it.
3. `LocalDateTime` does not have timezone information. If you want to display the timezone information, you should consider using `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. The following table shows [an overview of ***java.time*** data-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html):

[image]

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>◊ For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>