# Spring MVC: Convert String Date into Date over REST endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, date-conversion

I'm working on Spring boot project and I want to convert a String date coming from a post request

> D,100000001028686,BA0884,72087000000176,N,2,147568593,DEPOSITREFERENCE,**2020-08-05
> 20:17:33.32691**,
> 601123,ZAR,2500,57,24,i10c=0,i20c=2,i50c=5,iR1=2,iR2=5,iR5=8,iR10=200,iR20=1,iR50=55,iR100=60,iR200=82,0,0,0,0,000

The date that I want to convert is in **Bold** and need to convert that part from a `@PostMapping` method request parameter into one of the `java.time` Objects.

After searching I found some solution for the data if self without using `Spring` but it did not work for me and used `java.util.Date`, here the code I wrote so far

```
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "2020-08-05 20:18:33.32692";
        System.out.println(covertDate(date)); //Wed Aug 05 20:19:05 UTC 2020
      }
    
       public static Date covertDate(String date) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS");
            return formatter.parse(date);
        }
    }
```

The response I got is not what I'm looking for, is there any way to solve the problem

Comment: Do not longer use SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date. Use the modern java.time API available since java 8

Comment: @Jens , Plz can u clarify like just put me on the right direction and I will take from there

Comment: Please, when asking for help with code that doesn’t work, be precise about expected result and how observed result differs. Paste any error message into the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timestamp convert \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705924/timestamp-convert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `JShell (Java Version 14)` I ran your code and was able to get the similar  results (Granted it is in GMT and not UTC; however, the seconds are offset by the same amount as your current output):
[image]

If the question is about UTC:

I would suggest to use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) as it avoids many of the issues that [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) has presented over the years. As mentioned in the comments is it generally best to avoid using `java.util.Date` and to use `Instant` instead (or you could use the more traditional `LocalDateTime`).

If you are talking about `Spring`'s annotated `@PostMapping` method to parse out the date automatically you could use something like:

```
@PostMapping
public String postDate(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Long dateReq) {
  Instant date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateReq);
  System.out.println(date);
}
```

If you wanted to use your custom formatter the you could do `@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS" LocalDateTime date)` as the parameter of the `postDate` method.

Please note that `Spring`'s docs state that the pattern field of [`@DateTimeFormat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) uses the same patterns as [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). So that could be of use.

Comment: Thank @treedust for the response .I will take a look at it right away

Answer (score 2):

Here the solution I found after searching for future
I used Java 8 API to solve it

```
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String sDate6 = "2020-08-05 11:50:55.555";
    System.out.println(covertDate(sDate6)); //2020-08-05T11:50:55.555
  }

   public static LocalDateTime covertDate(String date) throws ParseException {
         DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
         LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date,formatter);
         return dateTime;  
    }
}
```